# Delete Data Api with Table have related another table .net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have problem delete data when Tables have related another table, when i tried this code with PostMan, i have error message "Invalid Columname TbRegistryId". in my table TbRegistry i didnt have Column TbRegistryId, but is just Id

Here My Models

```
public partial class TbRegistry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NoRisk { get; set; }
        public string Bproses { get; set; }
        public string Risiko { get; set; }
        public string AktivitasPengendalian { get; set; }
        public string Peristiwa { get; set; }
        public string PenyebabKrisiko { get; set; }
        public string KategoriRisk { get; set; }
        public string Sop { get; set; }
        public string PemilikRisiko { get; set; }
        public string UnitTerkait { get; set; }
        public string Kontrol { get; set; }
        public string TipeKontrol { get; set; }
        public string JustifikasiImpact { get; set; }
        public string JustifikasiLikelihood { get; set; }
        public string Kri { get; set; }
        public string RencMitiRisk { get; set; }
        public string TargetMitigasi { get; set; }
        public string Narasumber { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string UserInput { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateInput { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int? Flag { get; set; }
        public string Keterangan { get; set; }
        public string KodeUnit { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public string UserUpdate { get; set; }

        public TbMitigationPlan TbMitigationPlan { get; set; }
        public TbRegistryImpact TbRegistryImpact { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TbMitigationPlan> DataMitigation { get; set; }
    }
```

And Here My Controllers

```
        public IActionResult DeleteRisk(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                 var Risk = _context.TbRegistry.Where(x => x.Id == id);
                var Miti = _context.TbMitigationPlan.Where(a => a.IdRisk == id);
                var Impact = _context.TbRegistryImpact.Where(b => b.IdRisk == id);

                 if (Risk == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                _context.TbMitigationPlan.RemoveRange(Miti);
                _context.TbRegistryImpact.RemoveRange(Impact);
                _context.TbRegistry.RemoveRange(Risk);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you use Code-First?

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: So can you show use the definition of the database table?